# Regular Expression and operators

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a regular expression to remove all the operators that could be part of a equation string? Addition/Subtraction/Multiplication/Division

```
var l = "1+1-1*1\1";
var n = l.split(/\+/);//splits at +
```

Comment: Use `replace` instead of `split`

Comment: Good luck with that. What about functions like sin, cos, log, exp?

Comment: Divide symbol is "/" not "\"

Comment: @Bathsheba Not included in OP's explicitly stated list of relevant operators, so what about them?

Comment: Personally I find "all the operators that could be part of a equation string" to be contradicting that.

Comment: I am trying to break the equation apart at any and all operators. It is purely for updating visual number tiles ie. "1+2" will display the tiles one and two so it is not contradicting at all because it is a string representation of a equation. I am not trying to do the calculation. I am building a Bingo style game where you choose the answer to the equation question on a bingo board.

Answer (score 0):

`/[/+\-*]/g` = find all of '/','+','-','*'

note the `g` at the end means to find *all* matches in the input (not only once)

and note the '-' had to be escaped (using \  ie. `\-`) because it has special meaning inside the square brackets. The `+` and `*` have special meaning only outside square brackets, so don't need eascaping)

```
var equation = '4*2+5/3-8';

var removed = equation.split(/[/+\-*]/g);  

removed == [4,2,5,3,8]
```

Comment: I am actually looking for the result to be [4],[2],[5],[3] so removed.length would equal 4.

Comment: well then you were correct to use split, I'll update the answer

Comment: awesome, thanks! I actually found this out .split(/[\+\-\*\/]/ but cannot answer my own question for 8 hours because my reputation is too low. ;p

Answer (score 0):

Quick Update : I am matching images to the string equation because canvas font rendering is not all that hot. So I loop through the string checking for characters and then displaying the graphic that matches the character.

```
 var l = 1+1-1*1/1];
 var m = l.split(/([\+\-\*\/])/);

 console.log[m]// returns ["1", "+", "1", "-", "1", "*", "1", "/", "1"]
```

Then I just do a for loop and match the correct frames with the string value;

Example:
[image]